# Why does my react native function always return undefined?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-navigation

I am using react native and I have just migrated some database functions to a individual file, instead of just having them in the files where I need them (I have started needing to use the same functions in multiple files, and I'd rather have them all in one place). The problem is, the function that is supposed to compare a one time key with one in the database, always returns *undefined*.

I have tried returning functions instead of booleans, and have attempted to use "async/await" keywords (which I know very little about).

Here is my code...

**/project/src/components/Database.js**

```
var firebase = require('firebase');

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: "key",
        authDomain: "domain",
        databaseURL: "url",
        storageBucket: "bucket",
    });
}

class Database {
    constructor() {
      this.codesRef = firebase.database().ref('codes');
    }
    isValidCode(text) {
        let codeIsFound = false;
        let identifier = "";
        this.codesRef.once('value', (db_snapshot) => {
          db_snapshot.forEach((code_snapshot) => {
            //console.log(text, code_snapshot.val().value, text == code_snapshot.val().value);
            if (text == code_snapshot.val().value) {
              codeIsFound = true;
              identifier = code_snapshot.key;
            }
          });
          //console.log(codeIsFound); // this is correct
          return codeIsFound; // this always returns undefined
        });
    };
}

module.exports = Database;
```

**/project/src/components/forms/KeyForm.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';

import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

import database from '../Database.js';

const db = new database();


class LoginForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Access Code"
          returnKeyType="go"
          onSubmitEditing={text => {console.log(db.validCode(text.nativeEvent.text))}} // "undefined"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({\
  // yay styles :)
});

export default withNavigation(LoginForm);
```

Whenever I put a return statement *after* the firebase "once" function, it does return a boolean, but for some reason it is always false. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addressing this: *Whenever I put a return statement after the firebase "once" function, it does return a boolean, but for some reason it is always false.*

By removing the `.once()` method code, you can clearly see why this is the case. The code executes exactly as if it were written like below. Due to the async nature of the `.once()` method, the `return` statement executes prior to the `.once()` resolving (completing).

```js
isValidCode(text) {
  let codeIsFound = false;
  let identifier = "";
  // .once() goes here
  return codeIsFound;
};
```

Your instinct was a good one about async/await. To fix your issue, do this:

```js
async isValidCode(text) {
  let codeIsFound = false;
  let identifier = "";
  let db_snapshot = await this.codesRef.once('value');
   db_snapshot.forEach(code_snapshot => {
       if (text == code_snapshot.val().value) {
          codeIsFound = true;
          identifier = code_snapshot.key;
        }
   });
   return codeIsFound; 
};
```

Then, the function will return a promise that will be resolved (or rejected). So to use this code do:

```js
isValidCode('something').then(result => {
   /* use result here */
};
```

Comment: I think this is close, but it causes the function to return a "Promise" object instead of a boolean

Comment: Yes, of course. That is how [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) works. To use the value, do this: `isValidCode('stuff').then(result=>{ /* use result here */}`

Comment: This is definitely closer, but it returns `Object {
  "-LemIGLQEdkCniOFoi8d": Object {
    "value": "broIMI",
  },
  "-LemIbAmrtC9ABe9EXM2": Object {
    "value": "7xMbif",
  },
}`. I could definitely use this array / object with the keys to do the comparison inside of KeyForm.js, but I really wanted to have that taken care of inside of Database.js, and have a boolean returned. Any way to achieve that?

Comment: ARg - of course - I've returned the promise from the `.once()`. DS Passionate has the fix - I'll add here for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

[`once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) returns a `Promise<DataSnapshot>`, which means it is asynchronous and you cannot return a value from an asynchronous method.

To solve your problem, you can do the following:

```
    isValidCode(text) {
    let codeIsFound = false;
    let identifier = "";
    this.codesRef.once('value', (db_snapshot) => {
      db_snapshot.forEach((code_snapshot) => {
        //console.log(text, code_snapshot.val().value, text == code_snapshot.val().value);
        if (text == code_snapshot.val().value) {
          codeIsFound = true;
          identifier = code_snapshot.key;
          takeValue(codeIsFound);
        }
      });
    });
};

takeValue(value){
 console.log(value) //true
}
```

Here you create a new method inside `once()` and then add the value as a argument.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code still returns undefined with this modification. It successfully logs the value to the console, but I still don't know how to actually return it.

Comment: where are you returning it ?

Comment: I tried returning in the same place as in the question, and inside of the if(text==code_snapshot.val().value) {} condition.

Comment: as i said you cannot do that since it is asychronous, if you want to use the value of `codeisfound` somewhere else then add it as an argument to a method and use it in that method as in my answer

Comment: Ok but then how am I supposed to access that value from KeyForm.js? Would I have to change the value of onSubmitEditing?

Comment: since you are exporting `Database` then in `KeyForm.js` use the method `takeValue`

Answer (score 0):

As per @randy casburn problem is same.
Just modifying solution given by @randy.

```
    async isValidCode(text) { let codeIsFound = false; let identifier = ""; if(await this.codesRef.once function call ) {
Return true;
} else {return false;} };
```